# Trigger on Google Docs doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've written the following script for sorting the rows in my Google Docs Spreadsheet. When I click on the run button in the Script Editor it works. I've created an open-trigger in "current project triggers" but when I open the table the code doesn't run.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A2:M1000"); 
range.sort({column: 13, ascending: false});
```

}

Comment: Change the trigger notification to "immediately" so that if an error occurs you receive it right away and you'll know what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By open trigger, you mean a trigger that calls that function when the document is opened correct? in that case, instead of manually adding the trigger, do it programatically. Add the following function:

```
function onOpen(){
  Logger.log('Calling myFunction');
  myFunction();
}
```

and test it now.